# Django admin get_FOO_display

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I have model like this:

```
class M(models.Model):
    CHOICES = (('A', 'Accepted'), ('R', 'Rejected'))

    status = model.CharField(max_length=1, choices=CHOICES)
```

I register this model in admin by this way:

```
class MAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
     list_display = ('get_status_display', )
```

But I see field name *curried* in status column.

How I can give normal name *Status* to column or I make something wrong?

And can I sort by this field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the `short_description` attribute of your `get_status_display` callable to control the column name. You cannot sort by a calculated value (Django uses the database to do the sorting) but if your underlying `status` field gives the correct sort order, set the `admin_order_field` attribute to `'status'`.

The docs for `list_display` give examples of setting both attributes:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display

Since it's an auto-created method, it's marginally more complicated - the callable isn't available at class definition time. I **think** you can set them before registering the admin, but I haven't tested that:

```
M.get_status_display.short_description = 'status'
M.get_status_display.admin_order_field = 'status'
admin.site.register(M, MAdmin)
```

If that doesn't work, chasing down when exactly the choice field's `contribute_to_class` method gets called to add the auto-created method is one way to figure out when you can set those attributes. But I'd probably just skip it and stick a wrapper on the admin class, where I know I can set the attributes.

Answer (score 1):

Add these attributes to your function

```
def get_status_display(self, obj):
        --
        YOUR CODE HERE
        --
get_status_display.short_description = 'status'
get_status_display.admin_order_field = 'status'
```