# Display checkbox value from Database Django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-forms

I'm making a ModelForm. I have a Gender field in which I have given choices.In forms.py file I have converted those choices into checkbox using widget.

models .py

```
class UserModel(models.Model):
    #username=models.ForeignKey(
    #    on_delete=models.CASCADE,
     #   related_name='custom_user')

    name=models.CharField(
        max_length=50,
        verbose_name='Full Name',
    )

    gender=models.CharField(
        choices=(
            ('M','Male'),
            ('F','Female'),
        ),
        max_length=1,
        verbose_name='Gender',
        default='M'
    )
```

forms.py

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):


    class Meta:
        model=UserModel
        exclude=()
        widgets = {
            'DOB': forms.SelectDateWidget(),
            'gender':forms.RadioSelect(),
            #'hobbies':forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple()

        }
```

everything works fine and data is stored in database,But when I fetch data from the database in django shell using commands.Instead of getting the name of choice I get 'M',or 'F'. I know for choice field we can use `object_of_modelclass.get_gender_display` to get name of choice and it returns full name of choice. But since I have converted the choice to checkbox field in forms.py,now when I fetch data from database using `object_of_modelclass.get_gender_display` it returns

Django shell commands im using:

```
from .models import UserModel
a=Usermodel.objects.get(pk=1)
a.get_gender_display
```

it returns

```
functools.partial(<bound method Model._get_FIELD_display of <UserModel: hoo>>, field=<django.db.models.fields.CharField: gender>)
```

How can I get original name as "Male' and 'Female' ? Thanks

Comment: You haven't shown the relevant code here. *Where* are you calling `get_gender_display`?

Comment: in django shell by using comands,wait I'll update question @DanielRoseman

Comment: how about `a.get_gender_display()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should call the `get_FIELD_display` as a function, therefore using ().

```py
a.get_gender_display()
```

Comment: Thanks It worked.Can you explain why we have to call it as function?

Comment: Basically, all fields that has a `choices` has this method available which returns the value of the choice. You can check more [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_FOO_display)

Comment: how can I perform same functionality for admin site?

Comment: Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21242486/django-admin-get-foo-display)